# Using int64 as an iterator in a for loop

Tags: go, declaration

Within my loop, I am multiplying some int64's with my iterator. To do so, I need to explicitly declare `i` as int64. This

```golang
var other int64 = 1597183200000 
for var i int64 = 0; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Println(i*other)
}
```

gives a `syntax error: var declaration not allowed in for initializer`. Is there a way to do it right in the loop's initializer? Also, why is it not allowed to use `:=`, but not `var` in there? Don't they do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use short variable declaration in a for-loop. Since `0` is an untyped constant, it is assumed to be `int` unless you covert it to a different type:

```
for i:= int64(0); i < 10; i++ {
```

Comment: In other languages, you can do these sorts of casts like so: `12.3f`, or `12.3d`. Is that not possible in Go?

Comment: You can see the supported numeric literals here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals